# In Excel VBA using SAXXMLReader60 to parse multiple very large files. How to stop parsing document and go to next file?

Tags: excel, vba, sax, saxparser

I'm trying to parse large XML files relatively quickly in Excel VBA. In each file I only need to get information from the first few elements, then need to exit parsing and go to the next file. I implemented the ContentHandlerError but can't see how to raise it in order to gracefully drop back into the loop and parse the next file. Here is the code, I'd really appreciate any help!

```
Sub main()

    Dim saxReader As SAXXMLReader60
    Dim saxhandler As ContentHandlerImpl
    Dim saxerror As ContentHandlerError
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sFilePath As String

    sFilePath = "c:\testfiles\"
    sFolder = sFilePath & "*.xml"

    sFile = Dir(sFolder)

    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Debug.Print sFile

        Set saxReader = New SAXXMLReader60
        Set saxhandler = New ContentHandlerImpl
        Set saxerror = New ContentHandlerError

        Set saxReader.contentHandler = saxhandler
        Set saxReader.errorHandler = saxerror

        saxReader.parseURL "file://" & sFilePath & sFile

        Set saxReader = Nothing

        sFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endElement(strNamespaceURI As String, strLocalName As String, strQName As String)

    If strLocalName = "Series" Then

        'TODO:How to stop processing and go to next file?
    End If

End Sub
```